# how can i conditionally union with a select query that might be null in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a rather large sql query that works on two tables that have a parent-child relation realized by a foreign key constraint.
Let's say the tables are created like this:

```
drop table if exists table1 cascade;
drop table if exists table2;

create table table1 (
    segment_nr bigserial,
    part_id varchar,
    additional_data varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY(segment_nr)
);

insert into table1 values 
    (0, 'aaa', ''),
    (1, 'aaa', ''),
    (2, 'bbb', ''),
    (3, 'bbb', '')
;
    
create table table2 (
    s_id bigserial,
    segment_nr integer,
    ident varchar,
    val double precision,
    PRIMARY KEY(s_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_segmentnr
    FOREIGN KEY(segment_nr) 
    REFERENCES table1(segment_nr)
);

insert into table2 values
    (0, 0, 'cond1', random()),
    (1, 0, 'cond2', random()),
    (2, 0, 'cond3', random()),
    (3, 0, 'cond3', random()),
    (4, 0, 'cond4', random()),
    (5, 1, 'cond1', random()),
    (6, 1, 'cond2', random()),
    (7, 1, 'cond4', random()),
    (8, 1, 'cond4', random()),
    (9, 1, 'cond4', random()),
    (10, 2, 'cond1', random()),
    (11, 2, 'cond2', random()),
    (12, 2, 'cond3', random()),
    (13, 2, 'cond3', random()),
    (14, 2, 'cond3', random()),
    (15, 3, 'cond1', random()),
    (16, 3, 'cond2', random()),
    (17, 3, 'cond4', random()),
    (18, 3, 'cond4', random()),
    (19, 3, 'cond4', random())
;
```

what i want to do is select a join of table1 and table2 where i get all rows in table2 where ident is either `cond1` or `cond2`, i then want to union the results with a count of all rows that have `cond3` and `cond4` as ident.
This is the query i am working with so far:

```
with cte(part_id, segment_nr, ident, val, quantity) as (
select 
    t1.part_id, 
    t1.segment_nr, 
    t2.ident, 
    t2.val as measurement_value,
    1
    from table1 t1
join (
    select 
        segment_nr, 
        ident, 
        val 
    from table2 
    where segment_nr in (
        select segment_nr from table1 where part_id='aaa'
    ) and not ident = ANY('{cond3, cond4}')
) as t2
on t1.segment_nr = t2.segment_nr
order by t1.segment_nr asc
) TABLE cte
UNION ALL
select 'aaa', segment_nr, 'cond3', max(abs(val)), count(*) from table2 
where ident='cond3' and segment_nr in (select segment_nr from table1 where part_id='aaa')
group by ident, segment_nr
UNION ALL
select 'aaa', segment_nr, 'cond4', max(abs(val)), count(*) from table2 
where ident='cond4' and segment_nr in (select segment_nr from table1 where part_id='aaa')
group by ident, segment_nr
order by segment_nr, ident
```

now this works great for segment_nr=0 but for segment_nr=1 there is no row with "cond3".

```
part_id, segment_nr, ident, val, quantity
"aaa"   0   "cond1" 0.18490479540549032 1
"aaa"   0   "cond2" 0.9419814395776882  1
"aaa"   0   "cond3" 0.909608591110846   2
"aaa"   0   "cond4" 0.9377227138447388  1
"aaa"   1   "cond1" 0.38357500084326546 1
"aaa"   1   "cond2" 0.2261324685116186  1
"aaa"   1   "cond4" 0.9623352434184973  3
```

now the problem is that for segment_nr=1 the row with ident='cond3' gets omitted since there are no such idents in the table for this segment_nr. My question is how do i change the above query to insert a row with quantity 0 in this case?

i.e. a row that looks like this:

`"aaa" 0 "cond3" 0 0`

Comment: I did't really get into your query, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following revised SQL query, I introduced two additional Common Table Expressions (CTEs), `cond3_cte` and `cond4_cte`, to handle the cases of 'cond3' and 'cond4' separately. These CTEs use a LEFT JOIN between `table1` and `table2` to ensure that even if there are no matching rows in `table2` for a particular `segment_nr` and `ident`, a row with a quantity of 0 is still included in the output. The COALESCE function is used to replace NULLs in the count and maximum value columns with 0 for these cases. Finally, the results from the original CTE (for 'cond1' and 'cond2') and the new CTEs are combined using UNION ALL, and ordered by `segment_nr` and `ident`, to provide a comprehensive output that includes all scenarios.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        t1.part_id, 
        t1.segment_nr, 
        t2.ident, 
        t2.val AS measurement_value,
        1 AS quantity
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
            segment_nr, 
            ident, 
            val 
        FROM table2 
        WHERE ident = ANY('{cond1, cond2}')
    ) t2 ON t1.segment_nr = t2.segment_nr
    WHERE t1.part_id = 'aaa'
),
cond3_cte AS (
    SELECT 
        t1.part_id, 
        t1.segment_nr, 
        'cond3' AS ident, 
        COALESCE(MAX(ABS(t2.val)), 0) AS measurement_value, 
        COALESCE(COUNT(t2.s_id), 0) AS quantity
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.segment_nr = t2.segment_nr AND t2.ident = 'cond3'
    WHERE t1.part_id = 'aaa'
GROUP BY t1.part_id, t1.segment_nr
),
cond4_cte AS (
SELECT
t1.part_id,
t1.segment_nr,
'cond4' AS ident,
COALESCE(MAX(ABS(t2.val)), 0) AS measurement_value,
COALESCE(COUNT(t2.s_id), 0) AS quantity
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.segment_nr = t2.segment_nr AND t2.ident = 'cond4'
WHERE t1.part_id = 'aaa'
GROUP BY t1.part_id, t1.segment_nr
)
SELECT * FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cond3_cte
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cond4_cte
ORDER BY segment_nr, ident;
```